# Quiero insertar en la tabla compven: id_cliente e id_compra de la tabla carro, sin repetir id_compra

Tags: php

```
$v2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT id_compra FROM carro");
if(mysqli_num_rows($v2)>0){
}else{
$q2 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO compven (id_cliente,id_compra) VALUES ($id_cliente,$id_vendedor)");
}
```

Ejemplo:

Tabla carro:

### id_cliente |  id_compra

```
1       |      1                    
1       |      1
1       |      2
```

Quiero que aparesca, Tabla compven:

### id_cliente  |id compra

```
 1       |      1
 1       |      2
```

Comment: Saludos, no termino de entender lo que tratas de lograr, si pudieras editar y aclarar un poco te lo agradecería

Comment: Desconociendo las reglas de negocio que debes de cumplir y únicamente para el punto solicitado con agregarle el atributo `UNIQUE` a la columna de `id_compra` cuando creas la tabla debería de bastar a nivel de SQL para que no te permita insertar un `id_compra` que ya existe

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Me he permitido ampliar el dataset con un registro más que muestra que usar un `DISTINCT` sólo es la solución para el caso concreto que planteas:

```
CREATE TABLE carro(
  id_cliente int,
  id_compra int
  );
CREATE TABLE compven(
  id_cliente int,
  id_compra int,
  UNIQUE(id_compra)  
  );
INSERT INTO carro (id_cliente, id_compra) VALUES
  (1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1);
```

Una vez definida la tabla `compven` con la clave única que te recomienda @Aprendiz, el siguiente paso es insertar en bloque todos los registros de carro, *ignorando* los errores `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'id_compra'` y registre los válidos:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO compven (id_cliente, id_compra)
  SELECT id_cliente,id_compra FROM carro;
```

Así evitas el trasiego de registros entre el PHP y el MySQL, resolviéndolo internamente en el servidor de bases de datos.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Tan sólo me queda una duda sobre tu pregunta: ¿para qué usas el campo `id_vendedor` que no aparece en ninguna de las tablas? Si se trata de una errata, modifica la pregunta para que pueda modificar la respuesta.